# CameraX and FirebaseVision Image on Lollipop fails

Tags: android, camera, ocr, firebase-mlkit, android-camerax

I'm trying to creating an OCR POC with CameraX and FirebaseVision API.

I have setup the Analyzer, and in ImageAnalysis.Analyzer#analyzer() 
I'm getting callbacks with Image in format of yuv_420_888.

This seems to be the problem on Android 5.0, FirebaseVision is failing to recognise the text.

I tried to dump the bitmap using

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/common/FirebaseVisionImage.html#fromMediaImage(android.media.Image,%20int)

to external cache, to debug, and it turns out it's all green.

But the same setup works with other Android platforms.

I came across 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37014456

Which suggests there's an issue with YUV images fixed only after 5.1.

Can I somehow tweak CameraX to serve a format FirebaseVision recognises on Android 5.0?